# 1z0-071 oracle exam question which answers is correct?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I remember this question from exam ( I fail in exam) and need help to choose correct answer. I can't find this in Google.

> Which three statements are true about the Oracle join and ANSI join syntax?
> A. The Oracle join syntax supports natural joins.
> B. The Oracle join syntax performs less well than the SQL:1999 compliant ANSI join syntax.
> C. The Oracle join syntax supports creation of a Cartesian product of two tables.
> D. The SQL:1999 compliant ANSI join syntax supports natural joins.
> E. The Oracle join syntax performs better than the SQL:1999 compliant ANSI join syntax.
> F. The Oracle join syntax only supports right outer joins.
> G. The SQL:1999 compliant ANSI join syntax supports creation of a Cartesian product of two tables.

Comment: Sounds like your asking us to take your test for you.  please edit to include info where you are confused or what you have figured out.  we will help you get to the right answer but you should make effort to do yourself and then mention what you have tried.

Comment: Oracle supports and recommends the use of the ANSI `JOIN` syntax.  The question seems very, very out-of-date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - currently I find myself on a site with a long established code base and Oracle development standards which mandate implicit join syntax. So, regardless of what you personally think about the clarity and safety of the SQL:99 joins (and for the record I agree with you), there is still value in knowing the whole range of Oracle syntax, even if it's only to understand when and why we shouldn't use something.

Comment: Thank you for helping, my question has been edited, it is not all what  I wrote

Comment: @APC:  It is not quite fully comprehensive but:  "Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator. " from https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm#SQLRF52355.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - as I said, I agree with you: given a free choice I would always choose to use explicit join syntax (even despite the edge case bugs). My point is, we don't always have a free choice, which is my current situation. Also, there is a difference between choosing to use (or not use) a syntax option and asserting people should not know about it. Oracle supports two join syntaxes and people should understand both. From which it follows that it is legitimate for exams to quiz students on the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers the exam expects are:

> C. The Oracle join syntax supports creation of a Cartesian product of two tables.
> D. The SQL:1999 compliant ANSI join syntax supports natural joins.
> G. The SQL:1999 compliant ANSI join syntax supports creation of a Cartesian product of two tables.

C. is interesting, because Oracle (AKA SQL:89 compliant ANSI) join syntax doesn't have an explicit notation for CROSS joining: we just omit the relevant criteria in the WHERE clause. This makes it too easy to accidentally create Cartesian products, and is one of the arguments in favour of using SQL:99.

The fifth option highlights the problem with such exam questions:

> E. The Oracle join syntax performs better than the SQL:1999 compliant ANSI join syntax.

Whilst this is generally not true and performance is equivalent, there are edge cases where it is true, mainly related to outer joins. The more recent our version of Oracle the fewer and more edgy those cases become. It's not an argument for using the older syntax, just something to bear in mind. [Find out more](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/ansi-outer/).

---

> "What specific syntactical construct in Oracle is equivalent to CROSS JOIN?"

What the exam question refers to as "Oracle syntax" is the ANSI SQL 89 syntax of **implicit joins**. That is, there is no specific syntax for defining joins; rather the WHERE clause is used for declaring both join conditions and filter conditions. So, the equivalent of CROSS JOIN in the older syntax is simply the absence of a join condition in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thank you for help. I didnt find in google information, I am learning oracle but this question very confused, I havent any idea what the answer and not found in guide book 1z0-071.

Comment: Why isn't "The Oracle join syntax supports natural joins." true? In the Oracle syntax, I can write multiple where conditions on the common columns to reproduce the same result as a natural join. It's like writing where conditions to reproduce the inner join from JOIN table ON.

Comment: @Blaisem - being able to reproduce the same result set as a natural join is not the same as saying there is a **specific** syntactical construct.

Comment: The reply here states the Oracle syntax supports a cartesian product. I assumed this was also based on a workaround of simply selecting from multiple tables. What specific syntactical construct in Oracle is equivalent to CROSS JOIN?

Comment: @Blaisem - I actually addressed that point in my answer but I have expanded on it to make it clearer.